# "Error: Video could not be decoded" only when video tries to play in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, mp4, video.js, flowplayer

When trying to play/test a video (MP4) on my web page, I select the play button and see this every time:

> Video Could Not Be Decoded

That shows up after about 7 seconds of play in IE11, yet it plays fine in Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas?

Environment:

- video-js player-v4.11.4, with a flowplayer fallback
- IE11
- Windows 7 PC

Here is the player code:

```
<video id="_1200k.mp4" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
preload="none" width="445" height="340" controls
poster="[var.thumb_file]" data-setup='{techOrder: [‘flash’,’html5’}'>

<source src="http://..........s3.amazonaws.com/[var.video_play]"     type='video/mp4' />

<object class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="445" height="340"    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"    data="https://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
<param name="movie" value="/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["/[var.thumb_file]",     {"url": "http://.........s3.amazonaws.com/    [var.video_play]","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
<!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
<img src="[var.thumb_file]" width="640" height="264" alt="Poster Image"    title="No video playback capabilities." />
</object>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't personally tested this, I feel *very* confident saying that there's very little chance that the Flowplayer fallback works as a drop-in replacement for the Video.js swf. Why are you doing this in the first place, when Video.js has its [own fallback](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/)?

I'd be surprised if you weren't seeing other issues as well. For instance, the example you provided has invalid JSON in the `data-setup` attr, so that should throw a JSON parse error.

So back to the original question about Flash fallbacks...if you're attempting to play an mp4 back in IE11, why are you forcing Flash in the first place? IE11 supports [h264 natively](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4), so a Flash fallback is unnecessary.

Altogether, your `<video>` tag should look something like this:

```
<video id="_1200k.mp4" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none"
  width="445" height="340" controls poster="..." data-setup='{}'>
  <source src=".../movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks SO much for your "very confident" reply. Much appreciated. Yes, it seems to have resolved the "Video Could Not Be Decoded" issue, when I changed my code to your code suggestion, however, no player appears when viewed via IE8 now. Any ideas to get video-js to fallback to play in IE8? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Much thanks again.

Comment: Are you using the CDN version of Video.js or hosting it yourself? If you're hosting it yourself, there's a good chance you need to specify the SWF location. There are more details on this in the [setup guide](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/setup.md#self-hosted)

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. It appears that I am still seeing "Video Could Not Be Decoded" when an mp4 is played in IE11 using:       <video id="_1200k.mp4" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none" width="445" height="340" controls poster="..." data-setup='{}'><source src=".../....mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>

Comment: Are you using the CDN version or not? Just to reiterate, IE11 *should not* require a fallback for an h264 source. What happens if you use a vanilla video element?

Comment: Thanks. It is self-hosted. Can you explain what you mean by "vanilla video element", please? I'm getting "the video player aborted due to corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support" in IE11. I look forward to any additional help.

Comment: By "vanilla video element" I mean just a plain video tag without Video.js.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I change the video player code to vanilla element like this:                                                                              <video width="140" height="120" id=videoPlayer1 controls="controls"     poster="/video/countdown.jpg">
 <source src="/video/test.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 </video>
and put several on a page (each with a unique id and mp4), some play successfully and some don't. Any additional help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's really difficult (or impossible) for anyone to help you debug this without seeing what you're talking about. If some mp4s work and some don't, that makes me think the source files are bad, but that's purely a guess without seeing a reduced test case.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies